# Curl to yii1.1 action returns empty result

Tags: php, curl, yii

I want to submit some form data from one sub-domain to another sub-domain using curl (both are running yii1.1).

so the submitted data using form from any of the sub-domain should get store on another.

For that I want to use CURL.

```
$test = ['parentkey'=>['key'=>'value']];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https:demo1.com/post/create");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  http_build_query($test)  );
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
```

But when i send CURL request to another domain is return empty response.

I have disable CSRF verification Inside that controller but still same result

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }
```

How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Have you tried to set proper schema? `https://` instead of `https:`

Comment: @Justinas if i return something from index.php which is at root it works fine but if i return something from my controller/action it wont. So my request is reaching domain i guess

Comment: Then make sure you show errors and then try to identify error cause. Try using Postman or other tool to make requests without your cURL first

Comment: Try https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle and check for errors

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the two backslashes after "https:"

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://demo1.com/post/create");
```